# SPOJ ANARC07G Let go to the movies approach

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

In [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ANARC07G/) question we have to find the number of single and family tickets needed such that the price is minimum. If the price is same for many arrangements, then print the arrangement with minimum tickets.

**Problem Statement**
Movie theaters in Acmestan have two types of tickets: A single ticket is for exactly one person while a family ticket allows a parent and their children to enter the theater.  Needless to say, a family ticket is always priced higher than a single ticket, sometimes as high as ﬁve times the price of a single ticket.

It is quite challenging for families to decide which ticket arrangement is most economical to buy. For example, the family depicted in the ﬁgure on the right has four ticket arrangements to choose from: Seven single tickets; Two family tickets; One family ticket (for adam, bob, cindy)plus four single tickets for the rest; Or, one family ticket (for bob and his four children) plus single tickets for the remaining two.

Write a program to determine which ticket arrangement has the least price. If there are more than one such arrangement, print the arrangement that has the least number of tickets.

[image]

My DP approach is as follows:-

1. Make the family tree.
2. Each node should have fields min_tickets(i.e. minimum number of tickets) and min_price(i.e. minimum price). These fields denote the minimum amounts needed to take that person and his children out. Also, there are fields denoting the number of family tickets(fam_tickets) and number of single tickets(sin_tickets) involved in the process.
3. Start from the leaf nodes. Initialise `min_tickets=1` and `min_price= S`(i.e. price of single ticket), `fam_tickets=0`, `sin_tickets= 1`.
4. Now for other nodes take into consideration his children and grandchildren. F is the price of family ticket. For them:-

   > min_price= min(F + min_price of all grandchildren summed , S +
   >   min_price of all children summed)

   If a grandchild is NULL, we take the `min_price=0 and min_tickets=0`
5. To find out min_tickets, we derive it from the formation giving us minimum price. If both formations come down to the same price, we do:-

> ```
>  if(1+ min_tickets of all grandchildren summed > 1+ min_tickets of all children summed)  
>       min_tickets = 1+ min_tickets of all children summed;
>       fam_tickets= fam_tickets of all children summed;
>       sin_tickets= 1+ sin_tickets of all children summed;
>  else  
>       min_tickets = 1+ min_tickets of all grandchildren summed;
>       fam_tickets= 1+ fam_tickets of all grandchildren summed;
>       sin_tickets= sin_tickets of all grandchildren summed;
> ```

Is this solution correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks complicated (which is a bad sign), this problem seems very similar to minimum vertex cover problem. But DP is a correct choice I think.

Comment: I think your solution is correct. Are you facing any specific problem?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal...no..just wanted to check

Comment: @avinash I think SPOJ online judge would be better qualified than us to check your approach.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal....the comments below the question mention some problem in the input format/file...so I wanted to check if the problem was in my approach

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the situation that they buy two family tickets to get the maximum profit in your example?
It seems that in your solution, when dealing with the node of adam,

```
min_price= min(F + min_price of all grandchildren summed , S + min_price of all children summed)
```

will not work.

I don't know the details of your implementation, but this is a tricky part. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: @songlj...thanks...I missed that...but I think all I need to do is add  is 'F + min_price of all children summed'....correct?

Comment: @avinash yes, I think it should be something like "F+min(min_price of all children summed, min_price of all grandchildren summed). Please have a try. :)

Comment: You could do 

`min_price = min(F + min_price of all grandchildren summed , S + min_price of all children summed, F + min_price of all children summed)`